# Asymmetric cryptographic algorithm for large text data

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am looking for a solution that meets the following requirements:

Let's assume, there are: the Application installed on a computing device and controlling it, Users that use this application, and Maintainers, that provide some support for the application. Application has the Configuration, for example in the file or database. Configuration is updated manually by Maintainers when required, for example weekly. Configuration contains, for example, list of emails, Application sends it's alerts to. Let's assume, that it is not possible for Users to modify the Application in any way. Although, Application is written in Java, so it is easy for Users to copy and debug it. Internally, the Application decrypts the Configuration in the Application's memory, in order to use the Configuration.

Users shall able to view the Configuration from inside the Application. Users shall be unable to change the Configuration, or to use their own (which is basically the same), for example to change any email or remove existing email or add a new one.

Additional requirement, that is not mandatory: It shall not be possible to directly view the Configuration without the Application. I understand it's hardly really possible, so, it shall be at least just difficult, like decryption necessary to view the Configuration without the Application.

Question: how to achieve this and is it possible at all?

Possible solutions I can realize, and attacks:

1) To use some signing. To sign each Configuration with some Digest and to check the Digest in the Application then. Attack: as I understand, App shall calculate the Digest using the public key stored in it. Then the Application shall compare calculated Digest with the one provided with the Configuration. So, attack is simple : Users will modify the Configuration, then debug the Application, put a breakpoint on the place where Application has already calculated Digest for comparing it with the stored one, then Users could dump the calculated Digest and replace provided Digest with this calculated one.

2) To use hybrid encryption. In this case the attack is the same: breakpoint in the place where decrypted symmetric key is available, dump this key, then to use it for the new Configuration encryption.

3) To use asymmetric encryption. Maintainers encrypt Configuration with the public key, then Application decrypts the Configuration with the private key. Attack is simple : Users could dump private key from the Application and derive a new public key, then use it for encryption.

Is there a solution, like "encrypt with the public key, then decrypt with private" for large chunks of data (up to 10 kb), or maybe any other possible way to achieve that?

Thank you

<s>Colleagues,
I have an application that shall receive and store some read-only data. The data shall be available for users to read but not available to change. For example, assume that there are text files with data, that keep some texts available for end users to read but not available for edits. New files shall be periodically received by the application, and shall be available for users in the same read-only mode.
So, local content (for example files content) is accessible by users. Users can copy content from application, save decrypted copies and so on. The only thing I need to prevent, is to replace existing data with any other data, including changing the content or adding new by users. I do not need changes detection, I need to make changes impossible (ok, as hard as possible).
I suppose, that the easiest way to do that, is to encrypt data with some secret key and to include the public key in the app, so app could decrypt and show the data, but without the secret key users would not be able to change the content.
I know, that standard RSA supports just a small data blocks to encrypt, usually slightly less than the key length. (I made tests and found that for RSA 2048 Java throws an exception after 254 bytes)  I also read, that it's not a good idea to split source data to chunks and to encrypt these chunks then. I read that it is advised to use symmetric key, like AES,  for encryption and decryption, then to encrypt this AES key with RSA key pair.
I see a big (as I suppose) security risk in this scenario - as my app is written in Java, it's quite easy to debug it and to dump the decrypted AES key, then to use it for data modifications, even without any modifications of the application itself.
So, my question is: how to solve this problem and what is considered to be secure to use in such a case?
Thank you
Update:
Of course, users are able to copy the file and to use a copy as they want. The goal is, to disallow users to change data used by application, not a copy of these data. In case of asymmetric encryption it is easy to achieve - I encrypt data with my private key, pass to app, app in runtime decrypts data with it's public key and use. In case someone would like to change data, app would not decrypt the data properly and data will be spoiled and app would fail to work till data will be reverted back.</s>

Comment: If users can copy the data then you can't prevent them from changing it. I don't see that crypto enters into the question at all.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk With RSA it is easy to achieve for small (key len -pading) files. No goal to prevent users tocopy and change copied data, goal is to prevent users to change data in the app. Agree, it could be confusing. Will try to clarify the question.

Comment: I still don't understand. What does it mean to "change the data in the app" and how is that any different than copying the data and changing it?

Comment: You don't want to encrypt it, that's easy to circumvent. The best you can do is *sign* the data (files, or whatever) in a secure environment, and distribute the data along with the signature(s) with your app. The private key for signing never leaves your secure environment but the public key is embedded in your app. Then, prior to "serving" the content, you verify the signature and refuse to serve content that fails verification.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  for example, there's a file email.txt that contains an encrypted email address. App uses this file to read this email from it. Then app uses  this email to send emails to this address. User can see this email in the app but cannot change it. As if this file changed, app will decrypt it with it's key and the result will be garbage. You could read more about asymmetric ciphers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I suppose I explained my question clearly - how to use asymmetric cipher for large data. If i need advice about data signing, i will explicitly ask about that

Comment: This is my area of expertise so avoid talking down to me. Signing does use asymmetric cryptography and your encryption scheme is trivial to defeat because the key **must be present right in your app**. What you're actually struggling to describe is signing. *...decrypts data with it's public key...* and that is what signing is essentially.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I definitely know how signing works. In my use case I just cannot add any data, like signatures. Do not take offence, but I am really tired of most answers here, like: "how to use pump to pump water?" Answers: "you need to wash your hands twice a day!", "use bucket", "explain what do you need this water for" etc. Everytime I spend a lot of time to formulate my question to prevent these annoying meaningless answers, and every time I see a lot. The only good point is, that usually someone appears who knows the real solution

Comment: If you can distribute encrypted files then you can distribute signed files. There are schemes that are called ["signature with message recovery"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17802/description-of-signatures-with-message-recovery-as-in-iso-iec-9796-2-and-emv-si) schemes but they don't seem appropriate for your application.

Comment: Ok, now you want to explain me my requirements...

Comment: I would suggest signing, or authenticated crypto such as an AEAD primitive. ps. to answer your question with regard to how to secure private key used to encrypt AES key, answer is a KMS/HSM.

Comment: Ok, after reading all the answers and comments, i suppose i could clarify my requirements. Just don’t know, shall i ask another question or edit this

Comment: @Woodstock could you please give me the link to read about this?

Comment: Asked it also here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233250/prevent-app-configuration-from-modifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @President James K. Polk stated in one of his comments the only solution in my humble opinion is to **sign** the read-only data and **use it only if the data is verified**. In your "Possible solution & attack" section you write that the program compares some Digits that can easily been overwritten. Usually the signature is done with the (SHA256-)
hash of the data, but you can sign the complete data without hashing it first and 4 KB of data does not bring performance issues on my desktop Java.

I setup a full working example that simulates the maintainer-side and the app-side and as a little goodie I encrypt the plaintext with AES CBC (key generated out of signature). I know that this mode of encryption is not the "best way" as the data does not need to be kept totally secret but not direct visible it's a good solution.

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cyptosystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        System.out.println("Cryptosystem for \nhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361876/asymmetric-cryptographic-algorithm-for-large-text-data/62398723#62398723");
        System.out.println("Warning: this program is experimental and has no proper exception handling");
        byte[] plaintext = new byte[4000]; // content to get secured, provided by maintainers
        byte[] ciphertext = new byte[0]; // encryped plaintext
        byte[] dataForApp = new byte[0]; // initvector | ciphertext
        new Random().nextBytes(plaintext);

        // generate rsa keypair
        System.out.println("generate the RSA keypair");
        KeyPairGenerator rsaGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        rsaGenerator.initialize(4096, random);
        KeyPair rsaKeyPair = rsaGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = rsaKeyPair.getPrivate(); // for signature
        PublicKey rsaPublicKey = rsaKeyPair.getPublic(); // for verification, implemented in app resources

        System.out.println("sign & encrypt the plaintext");
        // signature done by maintainers
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(rsaPrivateKey);
        sig.update(plaintext);
        byte[] signature = sig.sign(); // provide to app as byte array, hexstring or base64 as you like
        // encrypt plaintext with signature
        byte[] initvector = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(initvector); // random initvector
        // you can use another aes mode for encryption e.g. gcm
        // you can use a hmac as key derivation ...
        // i'm using sha256 to get a 32 byte long key
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] aeskey = md.digest(signature);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aeskey, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivKeySpec = new IvParameterSpec(initvector);
        Cipher aesCipherEnc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        aesCipherEnc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivKeySpec);
        ciphertext = aesCipherEnc.doFinal(plaintext);
        // copy iv | ciphertext
        dataForApp = new byte[ciphertext.length + 16]; // initvector length 16 byte
        System.arraycopy(initvector, 0, dataForApp, 0, initvector.length);
        System.arraycopy(ciphertext, 0, dataForApp, initvector.length, ciphertext.length);
        // send the dataForApp to the app (as byte array, hex string, base64 as you like
        System.out.println("dataForApp length: " + dataForApp.length);

        // app side, receive dataForApp & signature, already has public key
        byte[] dataForAppApp = dataForApp.clone();
        byte[] signatureApp = signature.clone();
        System.out.println("decrypt and verify the signature");
        // get initvector & ciphertext
        byte[] initvectorApp = new byte[16];
        byte[] ciphertextApp = new byte[(dataForAppApp.length - 16)];
        System.arraycopy(dataForAppApp, 0, initvectorApp, 0, 16);
        System.arraycopy(dataForAppApp,16, ciphertextApp, 0, (dataForAppApp.length - 16));
        // decrypt data
        MessageDigest mdApp = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] aeskeyApp = md.digest(signature);
        SecretKeySpec keySpecApp = new SecretKeySpec(aeskeyApp, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivKeySpecApp = new IvParameterSpec(initvectorApp);
        Cipher aesCipherDec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        aesCipherDec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpecApp, ivKeySpecApp);
        byte[] decrypttext = aesCipherDec.doFinal(ciphertextApp);
        System.out.println("plaintext equals decrypttext: " +  Arrays.equals(decrypttext, plaintext));
        // don't use the ciphertext as the signature is not verified
        Signature sigApp = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sigApp.initVerify(rsaPublicKey);
        sigApp.update(decrypttext);
        boolean signatureVerified = sigApp.verify(signatureApp);
        System.out.println("signatureApp verified: " + signatureVerified);
        System.out.println("if verified == true we can use the decrypttext");
    }
}
```

Comment: Java 8 (52.0) RSASignature.class, even without sources, decompiled automatically by idea, line 142: return MessageDigest.isEqual(var2, var5);

Comment: well, now I understood at last. Thank you! lol ))))) just needed to debug an example really ))))

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology/2210#2210). Cryptography is very hard, and if you make any mistake, it will have vulnerabilities you could have avoided by using a well-established library to do the heavy lifting. You could, for example, use [libsodium](https://doc.libsodium.org/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox). It has many abstractions, and probably has a solution for what you need.

With that out of the way, let's discuss how that would make it safer: the user needs to be able to read the contents, but not edit it. What exactly do you mean by "cannot edit"? Can he not be able to modify anything locally, or just not be able to upload it to your server as if he was authorized to do so?

If the former, encryption can't help you much - you need to be able to decrypt it locally, so an attacker can always dump your process' memory to get to the data - sure it would be hard, but definitely possible. Just not allowing people to edit/save/download in your application would be the strongest guarantee you can get.

If the latter, then using authentication would be the way to go - be that a simple method like HTTP basic authentication with user and password, or signing the file to be uploaded. Dealing with authentication on your application's side would be the more practical way.

Comment: RSA and AES ain't mine, they considered to be industrial standards. I supposed I was as much specific as it is possible. By editing I mean what usually meant by that - the changing of the file content. I supposed it's clear. Thank you for your effort, but it looks like you answered some another question, not mine. Will edit my question to make it even more specific even for the people who didn't read it lol

Comment: RSA and AES are cryptographic primitives, capable of encoding a single block. To use them correctly for encrypting/signing a payload requires a well-specified algorithm/protocol, which if not using the correct padding, instructions and parameters will lead to easily breakable encryption. Really, don't use them directly, use a library, if you really need to.

Comment: To be clear: it is impossible to actually prevent an attacker with system privileges from changing data in your application; there will always be a way to modify your address space directly if they wish to do so. The best you can do is server-side validation of the client's response.

Comment: What response? What server? What privileges? What are you talking about?

Comment: If a solution to this existed, anti-cheat for games would be a solved problem, for example. But it's not, since there's no way to guarantee there are no modifications.

Comment: Modifications of what? Solution exists, but just for a limited size payload.

Comment: As President James K. Polk already explained, "encrypt data with some secret key", which with RSA means "signing", would not give you the guarantees you want. But if you really want to encrypt/sign a file bigger than a single RSA block, you can use [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption) (it has bindings for other languages, including Java). It just won't do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Asymmetric **encryption is done with the Public Key** and the **decryption is performed with the Private Key**. As the app has to be capable to decrypt the data the app needs to know the Private Key and that's the problem with the common used algorithms, because for RSA or ECIES the Public key can get derived from the Private key. Therefore it's not a real problem to derive the Public key and store changed/appended data after encryption with the Public key.

Second thing is - you did not specify how "large" your text will be - some KB, MB, GB?

Some months ago I tested some "new" algorithms that are "Post quantum safe" and as an example I used the McEliece Fujisaki algorithm that is available with the Bouncy Castle Crypto provider (I used version 1.65, bcprov-jdk15to18-165.jar).

The program creates a 50 MB large byte array that gets encrypted with the Public key and decrypted with the Private key.
<del>At the moment I did not find any Public key deriving methods so you definitely need to know the Private and the Public key.</del>
I did not test larger byte arrays because this parameter depends on the memory of the target system (you need the double memory
as the complete data is captured in ciphertextByte and then again in decryptedtextByte).

**Edit June 16th 2020:** President James K. Polk programmed a method that easily retrieves a public key from a given private key. The source is available in his GitHub-Repo (https://github.com/james-k-polk/McEliece/blob/master/McElieceRecoverPublicFromPrivate.java) and for later convenience shown at the end of this answer. **So everyone that has access to a private McEliece key is been able to encrypt data with the retrieved public key!** Thanks to President James for his help.

Here are the outputs on the console:

```
McEliece Fujisaki Pqc Encryption
key generation
PrivateKey length: 4268   algorithm: McEliece-CCA2 format: PKCS#8
PublicKey  length: 103429 algorithm: McEliece-CCA2 format: X.509

initialize cipher for encryption
pt length:    52428800 (50 mb)
ct length:    52429056 (50 mb)

initialize cipher for decryption
dt length:    52428800 (50 mb)

compare plaintext <-> decryptedtext: true
```

class McElieceFujisakiPqcEncryptionLargeData.java

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithRandom;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.mceliece.*;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastlePQCProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.mceliece.BCMcElieceCCA2PrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.mceliece.BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey;

import java.security.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class McElieceFujisakiPqcEncryptionLargeData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
        System.out.println("McEliece Fujisaki Pqc Encryption");
        if (Security.getProvider("BCPQC") == null) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastlePQCProvider());
            // used Bouncy Castle: bcprov-jdk15to18-165.jar
        }
        System.out.println("key generation");
        SecureRandom keyRandom = new SecureRandom();
        McElieceCCA2Parameters params = new McElieceCCA2Parameters();
        McElieceCCA2KeyPairGenerator mcElieceCCA2KeyGen = new McElieceCCA2KeyPairGenerator();
        McElieceCCA2KeyGenerationParameters genParam = new McElieceCCA2KeyGenerationParameters(keyRandom, params);
        mcElieceCCA2KeyGen.init(genParam);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = mcElieceCCA2KeyGen.generateKeyPair();
        AsymmetricKeyParameter mcEliecePrivateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        AsymmetricKeyParameter mcEliecePublicKey = pair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = new BCMcElieceCCA2PrivateKey((McElieceCCA2PrivateKeyParameters) pair.getPrivate()); // conversion neccessary only for key data
        PublicKey publicKey = new BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey((McElieceCCA2PublicKeyParameters) pair.getPublic()); // conversion neccessary only for key data
        System.out.println("PrivateKey length: " + privateKey.getEncoded().length + "   algorithm: " + privateKey.getAlgorithm() + " format: " + privateKey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("PublicKey  length: " + publicKey.getEncoded().length + " algorithm: " + publicKey.getAlgorithm() + " format: " + publicKey.getFormat());
        // generate cipher for encryption
        System.out.println("\ninitialize cipher for encryption");
        ParametersWithRandom param = new ParametersWithRandom(mcEliecePublicKey, keyRandom);
        McElieceFujisakiCipher mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher = new McElieceFujisakiCipher();
        mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher.init(true, param);
        // random plaintext
        byte[] plaintext = new byte[52428800]; // 50 mb, 50 * 1024 * 1024
        new Random().nextBytes(plaintext);
        System.out.println("pt length:    " + plaintext.length + " (" + (plaintext.length / (1024 * 1024)) + " mb)");
        byte[] ciphertext = mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher.messageEncrypt(plaintext);
        System.out.println("ct length:    " + ciphertext.length + " (" + (ciphertext.length / (1024 * 1024)) + " mb)");
        System.out.println("\ninitialize cipher for decryption");
        mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher.init(false, mcEliecePrivateKey);
        byte[] decryptedtext = mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher.messageDecrypt(ciphertext);
        System.out.println("dt length:    " + decryptedtext.length + " (" + (decryptedtext.length / (1024 * 1024)) + " mb)");
        System.out.println("\ncompare plaintext<-> decryptedtext: " + Arrays.equals(plaintext, decryptedtext));
    }
}
```

Public key Retrieval class by President James K. Polk, available under MIT-Licence:

```
package com.github.jameskpolk;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithRandom;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.mceliece.*;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.mceliece.BCMcElieceCCA2PrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.mceliece.BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.math.linearalgebra.*;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class McElieceRecoverPublicFromPrivate {
    private static final SecureRandom RAND = new SecureRandom();

    public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair generateKeyPair() {
        McElieceCCA2KeyPairGenerator kpg = new McElieceCCA2KeyPairGenerator();
        McElieceCCA2Parameters params = new McElieceCCA2Parameters();
        McElieceCCA2KeyGenerationParameters genParam = new McElieceCCA2KeyGenerationParameters(RAND, params);
        kpg.init(genParam);
        return kpg.generateKeyPair();
    }

    public static McElieceCCA2PublicKeyParameters recoverPubFromPriv(McElieceCCA2PrivateKeyParameters priv) {
        GF2mField field = priv.getField();
        PolynomialGF2mSmallM gp = priv.getGoppaPoly();
        GF2Matrix h = GoppaCode.createCanonicalCheckMatrix(field, gp);
        Permutation p = priv.getP();
        GF2Matrix hp = (GF2Matrix) h.rightMultiply(p);
        GF2Matrix sInv = hp.getLeftSubMatrix();
        GF2Matrix s = (GF2Matrix) sInv.computeInverse();
        GF2Matrix shp = (GF2Matrix)s.rightMultiply(hp);
        GF2Matrix m = shp.getRightSubMatrix();

        GoppaCode.MaMaPe mmp = new GoppaCode.MaMaPe(sInv, m, p);
        GF2Matrix shortH = mmp.getSecondMatrix();
        GF2Matrix shortG = (GF2Matrix) shortH.computeTranspose();
        // generate public key
        return new McElieceCCA2PublicKeyParameters(
                priv.getN(), gp.getDegree(), shortG,
                priv.getDigest());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        // generate a McEliece key pair

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair bcKeyPair = generateKeyPair();
        McElieceCCA2PrivateKeyParameters bcPriv = (McElieceCCA2PrivateKeyParameters) bcKeyPair.getPrivate();
        BCMcElieceCCA2PrivateKey priv = new BCMcElieceCCA2PrivateKey(bcPriv);

        // get the first public key

        McElieceCCA2PublicKeyParameters bcPub1 = (McElieceCCA2PublicKeyParameters) bcKeyPair.getPublic();
        BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey pub1 = new BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey(bcPub1);

        // Now generate a second public key for the private key

        McElieceCCA2PublicKeyParameters bcPub2 = recoverPubFromPriv(bcPriv);
        BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey pub2 = new BCMcElieceCCA2PublicKey(bcPub2);

        // print some info about sizes

        System.out.printf("Size of encrypted messages in bits(bytes): %d(%d)\n",
                priv.getEncoded().length, priv.getEncoded().length / 8);
        System.out.printf("private key length: %d\n", bcPriv.getK());
        System.out.printf("public key1 length: %d\n", pub1.getEncoded().length);
        System.out.printf("public key2 length: %d\n", pub2.getEncoded().length);

        // now encrypt different messages with each public key.

        String message1 = "Deposits should be made to account # 3.1415929";
        String message2 = "Deposits should be made to account # 2.71828";

        ParametersWithRandom params1 = new ParametersWithRandom(bcPub1, RAND);
        ParametersWithRandom params2 = new ParametersWithRandom(bcPub2, RAND);

        McElieceFujisakiCipher mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher1 = new McElieceFujisakiCipher();
        McElieceFujisakiCipher mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher2 = new McElieceFujisakiCipher();
        mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher1.init(true, params1);
        mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher2.init(true, params2);

        byte[] ciphertext1 = mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher1.messageEncrypt(message1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] ciphertext2 = mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher2.messageEncrypt(message2.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("ct1 length:    " + ciphertext1.length + " (" + (ciphertext1.length / (1024 * 1024)) + " mb)");
        System.out.println("ct2 length:    " + ciphertext2.length + " (" + (ciphertext2.length / (1024 * 1024)) + " mb)");

        mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher1.init(false, bcPriv);
        mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher2.init(false, bcPriv);

        byte[] decryptedtext1 = mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher1.messageDecrypt(ciphertext1);
        byte[] decryptedtext2 = mcElieceFujisakiDigestCipher2.messageDecrypt(ciphertext2);

        System.out.printf("Decrypted message 1: %s\n", new String(decryptedtext1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.printf("Decrypted message 2: %s\n", new String(decryptedtext2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you, will try it tomorrow, it's 1:40am here now. Looks like it's exactly what I need. A quick question - I thought that it is possible to encrypt with the public key and decrypt with private as well. And I supposed that it will eliminate derived keys problem. Am I wrong? Regarding data size - the database column to store this is currently defined as NCLOB(4096) , if I remember correctly. So, not too big although larger tha nmax  RSA key supported by java.security

Comment: The sample program encrypts with PUBLIC key and decrypts with PRIVATE key as written in my answer. The derived keys problem will rise when there is an algorithm to do that (I did not found one but I'm not the crypto expert like others here on SO). 4 MB of data is definitely not a problem as the example works with a 50 MB byte array. 1:40am means "Eastern Europe" and 1 hour ahead of Germany :-)

Comment: It's 4 kilobytes, not mega. 1:40am also means Jerusalem time ;) Thank you for your help, mate!

Comment: Why do you believe the public key, or rather *a* public key, cannot be derived from the  private key?

Comment: @President James K. Polk: I know that a RSA and ECIES Public key CAN get derived from a Private key. Regarding the "new" McEliece-algorithms I did not see any information regarding a key derivation, therefore I wrote "The derived keys problem will rise when there is an algorithm to do that". Do you know any way to perform such a derivation?

Comment: I don't much about post-quantum crypto in general or McEliece in particular. Just lookin the steps in [key generation as described in WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem#Key_generation) I see no barriers to generating another generator matrix G' and G'_hat = S*G'*P. It looks like (G'_hat, t) is another public key for the same private key and thus any message encrypted with (G'_hat, t) will also be decrypted by the same private key.

Comment: When dealing with cryptography, you should only depend on things the cryptographic system provides you. If "not having the public key derived from the private key" is not a goal of the system, then you absolutely should not rely on that property on the grounds of "seems like nobody did it yet".

Comment: I was wrong about creating an *equivalent* public key, but I was able to recover the actual public key solely from an instance using [this code](https://github.com/james-k-polk/McEliece/blob/master/McElieceRecoverPublicFromPrivate.java). If you could look it over and see if it makes sense I'd appreciate it. I have to thank you, I had fun playing around with the Bouncycastle McEliece code.

Comment: @President James K. Polk: I tested the retrieval method and I could successfully retrieve a working public key from a private key. As I'm working on a smartphone I will edit my answer above accordingly. To make it short for now: as we do have a retrieval function now anyone have access to the private key is been able to encrypt data. Thanks and my pleasure to bring you some fun on a sunday :-)

Comment: Ok colleagues, thanks to your comments, I found my mistake in the requirements explanations. Now I’m not sure, could I add/edit my question or add a new one? Please advise

Answer (score 1):

> I know, that standard RSA supports just a small data blocks to encrypt,

That's why we use a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). Data are encrypted using a symmetric cipher (data key), and the symmetric data key is encrypted using an asymmetric cipher.

> I do not need changes detection, I need to make changes impossible (ok, as hard as possible).

If you are unable to enforce any read-only input/filesystem, then detecting changes is the best you can do. Either it's failed decryption or signature.

Actually to ensure data integrity I'd really use signing, not pure encryption. I see you don't want that, but at the end it will there. Some ciphers / cipher modes are malleable - data can be changed even when encrypted and without any authentication (mac, signature) the decryption is valid and you won't be able to detect the integrity failure.

If you would just rely on application to detect that data are corrupted after failed decryption, you are creating a perfect decryption oracle (breaking security)

> I suppose, that the easiest way to do that, is to encrypt data with some secret key and to include the public key in the app, so app could decrypt and show the data, but without the secret key users would not be able to change the content.

Anything hardcoded in your app you can consider as revealed/public. You correctly identified the risk. If you have a dedicated user, nothing prevents the user to change the key in the app and pass invalid data. So - for anything that runs at the client, you can make the integrity stronger, but not perfect. At the end - you have to make some assumptions about adversary's abilities.

> I encrypt data with my private key, pass to app, app in runtime decrypts data with it's public key and

In theory (mathematically) you can do that, but most of the current libraries will not let you use the key pairs wrong way (private key is intended for decryption or signing, public for encryption or validation). If you want to code such a solution yourself, you are in risk of creating weaknesses you may not be aware of (proper padding, timing,..)

I believe there are even some weaknesses in the scheme (encrypting using the private key), but I cannot recall details, there are people with deeper knowledge in the topic (e. g. James Polk from comments)

Edit:

Examples to create a signature or MAC : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html

btw - using aes-gcm the Java Cipher implementation automatically appends the mac tag to the end  of the ciphertext

Comment: 1) I know what hybrid encryption is. I use it. It is not suitable in this case because it is quite easy to retrieve a symmetric key.

2) Yes, all this task is about changes detection. The only question - how to do that? I have no idea about how to implement such a signing. Let's suppose that there's a digest distributed with each data. Users can just debug the application and obtain the digest, calculated by application for changed data, then to replace provided digest with the calculated one.

Comment: 3) I tried RSA and it supports. I asked on the "security" site, and people there told me mthere are such an algorithms but closed my question then lol. Also tried bouncy castle's ciphers and can't get any to do that.

Unfortunately, people there are quite angry of the fact, they do not know the answer, to they just give me meaningless advises about my requirements and other useless replies, like "it is very, very complicated", instead of any crypto recommendations

Comment: @BbIKTOP 1 - it's not easy/possible to retrieve a key when done properly.  2 - as you already found out, digest (hash) only doesn't help to detect changes. You need signing (rsa signature is a digest with decryption operation on it with proper padding) or authenticated encryption (aes-gcm, hmac, ..). 3 - Some people are angry, because they told it right (maybe not explained in length), but you refused to understand. As well creating your own schemes is not complicated, but prone to creating weaknesses you may be not aware of.

Comment: @BbIKTOP  you are changing scope of the question, then the question may and will get closed. The answer still assumes integrity of the application. If you give the user (adversary) ability to change the validation/decryption keys, then indeed you have no means to control what's happening on the user's hardware.

Comment: 1) for example? 2) i meant signed digest, of course. There’s also no server to implement authentication, if i understand you right  3) I see it differently. It looks like: “change your requirements so my answer will be valid”

Comment: why, i just rewrote the question explaining it further by adding details i missed as important. What do you think, shall i ask a new question then?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. As far as I can see from your question, the data itself is not secret. Your problem is that the user should not be able to change the data (or that you should be able to detect that he or she has changed it). In this case, a hash function (including possibly a cryptographic hash function) might well be a better approach. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function. If you use a hash function, then you can always detect whether the user has tried to change the data.

The cryptographic hash functions are one-way, so that you do not need to store any key in your program.

Comment: No, I don't need detection. I just need to prevent users to change existing data and to add their own. Asymmetric encryption suits my scenario, except it is not applicable for large data chunks. i edited the question to reflect that